# Cache busting with Compass sprite

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm using cache busting with images in compass:

```
asset_cache_buster do |http_path, real_path|
  if File.exists?(real_path)
    hash = Digest::MD5.file(real_path.path).hexdigest
    "v=%s" % hash[0,5]
  end
end
```

Using `image_url()` will append the `v`.

How can I accomplish the same behaviour using a sprite?:

```
@import '../images/navbar/*.png';
@include navbar-sprite;
```

I tried this but threw compass syntax errors:

```
@import image-url('../images/navbar/*.png');
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for compass spriting is almost that, except that it alters the name of the file, rather than changing a query string. Check the file system and/or the output css. Are you not seeing an generated image with a url like `/images/navbar-s34fe0604ab.png`? That name will change anytime any of the files inside `/images/navbar/` change.